# How to create an audio file from mediaplayer

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

I am currently developing an Android application which must be able 
to stream music from youtube and only download the audio.

I have already managed to:

1. Recover the url rtsp with youtube data API
2. Play music using the mediaplayer class.

Now, I would like to download music on my device.

Is this possible to do it directly via mediaplayer?

- if so how?
- If not? would it make a another way to do it?

Thank you to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can doing something like Inspect Element on Youtube-mp-3.org website :

1) Submit your Youtube URL to Youtube-mp-3.org
2) Inspect the response from the webservice
3) Build the donwload link by following the pattern They are using.
Example :

Youtube url : youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE ;

Request to webservice in the content body: KMU0tzLwhbE

Response from webservice : info = { "title" : "Developers", "image" : "i.ytimg.com/vi/KMU0tzLwhbE/default.jpg", "length" : "3", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "ping.aclst.com/ping.php/10754233/KMU0tzLwhbE?h=401301", "h" : "e8e446dbd937a0d8f636fdc8d8bb9874" };

Download link : http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&h=e8e446dbd937a0d8f636fdc8d8bb9874&r=1388680822878.1534658195

Hope it helps! Think about it..

Comment: thank you , i'm gonna try to understand how it works :D

Comment: @Thaoer Zaghal, The processing can't be saw from the web site :/ , do you have another idea ? ^^